# How can I fix a leaky door with new compression stripping?

Tags: insulation, weatherstripping

I have two exterior doors that are leaking air, they shut fine and the weather stripping is the original installed when the house was built about 8 years ago (with the exception that I replaced today).

The doors use compression weatherstripping like this: http://www.lowes.com/pd_29415-81-91868_4294929691__?productId=1082127&Ns=p_product_qty_sales_dollar|1&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNs%3Dp_product_qty_sales_dollar|1&facetInfo=

However, it doesn't fill the entire gap. The back door does seal if I press on the door once it's closed (it has to move about 3mm to seal the gap). But I can't figure out how to make it close more tightly. The front door, the door isn't completely square the the gap at the bottom is wider than the strip.

What should I do to seal my doors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something moved or warped. The door, the door jambs, the wall...

Easiest thing to do is add additional weather stripping. They make weather stripping that comes on either wood or aluminum strips for attaching to the door jambs. Comes with either the D style weatherstrip or the kerf style which you purchased. It's basically what you bought with a rigid piece that you can drive screws through. Kits come with 2 long pieces for the sides and 1 for the top.

Cut each to size place on door stop on outside of door and screw it into place. If the door isn't perfectly plumb you can install it a little off plum. If there's a little warp in the door you can notch the back of the aluminum ones to bend it into shape a little.

Lock your door, including deadbolt then attach them from the outside making sure not to press them up against the door too tight or you won't be able to unlock the deadbolt.

Answer (score 2):

For the back door, you can move the strike in towards the door stop the 3mm you need to get it to contact the weather stripping. Be careful how you do this, it will require a bit of cutting out of the jamb to move it back and reset longer screws to hold it there. Move it no more than you need, too much will make the door difficult to latch when you close it.

For the front door, you can loosen the screws going into the jamb and place cardboard shims the way I described in a [earlier post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59040/i-replaced-my-door-hinges-and-now-the-door-is-too-tight-at-the-door-jam-why/59044#59044) to divide the gap on either side of the door. Otherwise, pop the trim and reshim the jamb to get the gap closer so the seal fits better. Before you go into all that, check the tightness of the screws at all hinges before you start, you do not want any to spin as if it is not grabbing any wood. If you do find any spinning, your best bet will be to replace the short original screws with 1" to 1 1/2" longer ones. Be carful how tight you get these, they will move the jamb over more and make the problem bigger. Check the gap at the hinge side too. It may be tight so it would confirm the shims at the hinge are the fix, if not part of it.